# moving from recursive to non-recursive build system

Tags: makefile, build, autotools, autoconf, automake

I am trying to update our build system to be non-recursive. The current layout of the system (in which we build both GNU Octave and Matlab mex files) is:

```
---project/
|  ---mex/
|  |  +--src/ (contains common source files)
|  |  +--matlab-mex/ (contains compiled Matlab mex files)
|  |  +--octave-mex/ (contains compiled Octave mex files)
|  |  ---build/
|  |  |  mex1.am
|  |  |  ...
|  |  |  mexN.am
|  |  |  ---matlab/
|  |  |  |    Makefile.am
|  |  |  |    configure.ac
|  |  |  |    commonmex.am
|  |  |  |    ---mex1/
|  |  |  |    |    Makefile.am
|  |  |  |    ...
|  |  |  |    ---mexN/
|  |  |  |    |    Makefile.am
|  |  |  +--octave/ (... same layout as project/mex/build/matlab/)
```

Currently, `commonmex.am` contains the line `EXEEXT=$(MEXEXT)`, allowing `mex` files to compiled with the appropriate extension (`.mex`, `.mexmaci`, `.mexmaci64`, etc.) depending on the Matlab version and OS system/architecture found by `configure`. As a recursive system, this works quite well.

**Issue**

In the move to a non-recursive build system (having read [autotools-mythbuster](http://karelzak.blogspot.fr/2013/02/non-recursive-automake.html) and [Karel Zak's blog](https://autotools.io/automake/nonrecursive.html)), instead of using `SUBDIRS`, I `include` `commonmex.am` and the `mex*.am` in `project/mex/build/matlab/Makefile.am`. The problem I encounter in making this change is that I am not able to overwrite `EXEEXT` as above. When I run `autoreconf -si` I get the following warning:

```
./commonmex.am:1: warning: EXEEXT was already defined in condition TRUE, which includes condition DO_SOMETHING ...
Makefile.am:10:   'mex1/mex1.am' included from here
mex1/mex1.am:1:   './commonmex.am' included from here
configure.ac:59: ... 'EXEEXT' previously defined here
```

**NB:** `if DO_SOMETHING` is a conditional in `Makefile.am` that wraps the entire Makefile such that it is ignored if the person building has one of GNU Octave or Matlab but not the other.

When I run `make` the `mex` files are built but without any extension at all (I'm building on macOS, but the result would be the same on GNU/Linux I imagine). As we compile these mex files for distribution on GNU/Linux, macOS, AND Windows, the extension is quite important for us.

How can I move to a non-recursive build system while overwriting the `EXEEXT` set in `configure.ac` with the `MEXEXT` variable, also set in configure.ac?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it was easy. Just overwrite the definition of `EXEEXT` in `configure.ac`:

```
EXEEXT=$MEXEXT
```